How to set \baselineskip in a class file?
I want to change the length of \baselineskip for my latex documents. This is my test document:
\documentclass{testlayout}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus

\end{document}

And this is a test class file. I use the geomtry package to set the size to A4, and then want to change the length of \baselineskip to zero:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testlayout}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{
    \fontsize{12}{24}
    \selectfont
}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=10mm,
    bottom=10mm,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{0mm}

But the output PDF still has the same lineheight as always. I tried other values, also very high ones like 100mm, but it seems like Latex is just ignoring that line. However, when I add the \setlength{\baselineskip}{0mm} to my actual document, then it works. I thought that I'm maybe using classes in a wrong way here, but I'm actually able to set other lengths like \parindent in the class file, so it seems like Latex is just ignoring specific sizes.

why would you ever want \baselineskip to 0? that is telling TeX to try and fail  set 12pt high letters on a line without moving the current point down at all so the next line overprints. With the default value of \lineskiplimit  this won't happen and the baselineskip will not be used at all, but there is no possibility of reasonable typography with that setting.

Also, \baslineskip gets reset (between paragraphs) when you change font sizes.

Requesting a baselineskip of 0pt is requesting this output

as you are placing each line of the paragraph on lines 0pt apart.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-20pt}% so the above setting is used.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis
pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus

\end{document}

The default value of \lineskiplimit is 0pt so LaTeX does not allow overprinting here and a different spacing is used ignoring the \baselinesetting if it would overprint, so you get

\documentclass{article}
\showoutput \showboxdepth=3
\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
%\setlength\lineskiplimit{-20pt}% so the above setting is used.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis
pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus

\end{document}

But this isn't really much better typographically, as \baselineskip is being ignored you get a fixed \lineskip (1pt) space between each line and Tex gives up producing even line spacing, lines that happen to have capital letters or descenders get more space than lines that do not.

The baselineskip is set for each font size, as the second argument to \fontsize, defaulting to pt. It is customary to use around 120% of the nominal font size, although some fonts look better with larger or smaller spacing and some documents with many inline formula or other large inline constructs benefit from a larger baseline skip so that an even spacing can be achieved.  A value of the nominal font size or less will almost always result in uneven line spacing in the document as tex will not be able to achieve the specified line spacing without adjusting the position of each line based on the content of that line.

Zero was just for test cases. I just wanted to make it smaller

@axolotlKing0722 I added some notes at the end

Ok my dumb ass just found the problem. It's obviously because I set the line height to 24pt here:
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{
    \fontsize{12}{24}
    \selectfont
}

So I can change it to \fontsize{12}{12} or \fontsize{12}{0} or whatever I want. No need to set \baselineskip

\normalsize should do much more than that.

if you change it to 0 you will get uneven linespacing throughout the document, you are also inserting two space characters every time \normalsize is used. The command should also set up the spacing for lists and other things suitable for this font size.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
